# GC overhead limit exceeded when querying on OrientDB

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, orientdb

My database has 200.000 documents, linked with a property that has 6 million documents. When I query it, for some queries, the error GC overhead limit exceeded appears.

My computer has 16GB of RAM and I give 8 GB to OrientDB (-Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=8192) and put -Xms1024 -Xmx2048. And I've tried other options like: -Xms128 -Xmx4096, and other options.

Can someone help me how to fix it? Or isn't OrientDB good enough to work with this amount of data?

My data is something like this:

```
{"@type":"d","@class":"part","p_partkey": 2, "lineorder": [{"@type":"d","@class":"lineorder","customer": [{"@type":"d","@class":"customer","c_city": "INDONESIA1"}], "lo_supplycost": 54120, "orderdate": [{"@type":"d","@class":"orderdate","d_weeknuminyear": 19}], "supplier": [{"@type":"d","@class":"supplier","s_phone": "16-789-973-6601|"}], "commitdate": [{"@type":"d","@class":"commitdate","d_year": 1993}], "lo_tax": 7}, {"@type":"d","@class":"lineorder","customer": [{"@t...
```

There are 200 thousand part of class part with one property lineorder type linklist, each part have more than one lineorder of class lineorder with 4 properties, customer, supplier and commitdate, all linkedlist too.

An example of queries:

```
select sum(eval("line.lo_extendedprice * line.lo_discount / 100")) as revenue 
from (select lineorder as line from part where lineorder.orderdate contains (d_year=1993) unwind line)
where line.lo_discount between 1 and 3 and line.lo_quantity<25 and line.orderdate contains (d_year=1993)
```

Comment: Hi @Raphael, how is your DB structured (classes,...) ? Which query/queries did you execute to get this error ? BTW, if you had a small DB test to reproduce your issue it would be great.

Comment: @LucaS, I've tried it with a smaller database and it works, but after I insert everything the same query returns this error. I'll put an example of my data above.

Comment: Hi @Raphael, I'm trying to reproduce the dataset. Do you have indexes on some properties ? This could speed up your queries.

Comment: Another thing: the class `Lineorder` also contains the properties `lo_supplycost`, `lo_tax`, `lo_discount`, `lo_quantity` and `lo_extendedprice` right ?

Comment: @LucaS, I haven't created indexes because the fields that I queried are not unique and they are repeated a lot of times.

Comment: @LucaS, I have notice that the query above dont have ask for atributes from part and I queried directly to lineorder, but the results returned are wrong, you know why?

Comment: Hi @Raphael, thanks for the answer. I supposed that you could have created a `NOTUNIQUE` index on some fields.

Comment: @LucaS I've tried it yesterday but it didnt work.

Comment: @LucaS, I have others queries that uses part propreties, like p_category and I have the same problems wth GC.

Comment: Hi @Raphael, I'm trying to reproduce it. About the wrong results you mentioned, I don't know which is your output.

Comment: Hi @LucaS, I have found a solution for my problem, I have not solved the OrientDB problem with the unwind but I think you would like to know how I solved my problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Raphael, great! I'll try your solution.

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot of things the only way I could get the answers was avoiding the unwind operation on the sub-queries responses when it returns a lot of documents. To do it I have to create relationship between the lineorder (second level of nested documents) and the part, in this case the classes have to have common fields, in my case lo_partkey for the class lineorder and p_partkey for the  class part, so I could create the relationship this way:

```
create link ordered type linkset from lineorder.lo_partkey to part.p_partkey
```

So this way I could avoid unwind a lot of documents and get or query the parent atributes i want from the child (lineorder in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Orient has two types of memory: heap and disk-cache.
If the heap is too low you risks the memory overflow because you have less memory than what you need. The heap memory is necessary.
The disk-cache is used for the performances, more higher is the memory and more higher are the performances, if you don't have enough disk-cache, the performances descrease.
The disk-cache must be at most as large as the database.
You have to increase the heap memory and decrease the disk-cache memory.

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: Has The disk-cache must be at most as large as the database or at least? Isn't it contraditory? If I decrease the disk-cache wont I decrease the performance?

Comment: Hi @Raphael the disk-cache must be at most large as the database, yes if you decrease the diskcahe you will lose the performances